Adding a tag for scrolling and continuously scrolling to the bottom?
Following this I have implemented a container for continuously capturing R console output including scrolling capabilities.
Prompted by a comment below, I have generated a minimal example which looks like this (console output here is simulated by adding lorem ipsum text):
library(magrittr)
pkgs <- c(
  "lorem",
  "shiny",
  "shinyjs",
  "stringi"
)
for (pkg in pkgs) requireNamespace(pkg)

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shiny::sidebarPanel(
    shiny::actionButton(
      inputId = "loreming",
      label   = "Add more"
    )
  ),
  shiny::mainPanel(
    shiny::verbatimTextOutput("muchlorem", placeholder = TRUE),
    shiny::tags$head(
      shiny::tags$style(
        "#muchlorem{overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 200px;}"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  shiny::observeEvent(input$loreming, {
    shinyjs::html(
      id = "muchlorem",
      html = lorem::ipsum(5) %>%
        stringi::stri_wrap(prefix = "\n") %>%
        paste(collapse = ""),
      add = TRUE)
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)

I am aiming at a scroll state that automatically scrolls to the end of the muchlorem whenever something is added. How would that be achievable?

In your example you have an observeEvent on input$loreming in which the shinyjs::html() is added. After this is appended, you can execute the JS
var objDiv = document.getElementById("muchlorem");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

which scrolls the container with id = "muchlorem" to the bottom. I implemented this below using shinyjs::runjs().

library(magrittr)
pkgs <- c(
  "lorem",
  "shiny",
  "shinyjs",
  "stringi"
)
for (pkg in pkgs) requireNamespace(pkg)

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shiny::sidebarPanel(
    shiny::actionButton(
      inputId = "loreming",
      label   = "Add more"
    )
  ),
  shiny::mainPanel(
    shiny::verbatimTextOutput("muchlorem", placeholder = TRUE),
    shiny::tags$head(
      shiny::tags$style(
        "#muchlorem{overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 200px;}"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  shiny::observeEvent(input$loreming, {
    shinyjs::html(
      id = "muchlorem",
      html = lorem::ipsum(5) %>%
        stringi::stri_wrap(prefix = "\n") %>%
        paste(collapse = ""),
      add = TRUE)
    shinyjs::runjs('
                   var objDiv = document.getElementById("muchlorem");
                   objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
                   ')
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)


